# using BufferedReader read remote file metadata

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am reading file from remotely using BufferedReader and i can run every line of the file using below program.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.statvision.com/webinars/countries%20of%20the%20world.xls");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        long rowcount=0;
        while ((reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            rowcount=rowcount+1;
        }
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(rowcount);

    }
```

But i want to read the remote file metadata. I mean i want to read file creating time,author name. But not get any way to read the remote file metadata!!

Any type of help or suggestion will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The metadata itself is stored in the file itself. You can use one of the Java libraries to open the file and extract the metadata. You can look at Apache POI for that.